# Font awesome icon weird inner border/shadow

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, materialize

Okay, so i don't know what is wrong with my font awesome icons but basically it's looking like a shadow/border is inside it and the icons look very weird.

If anyone can suggest what it is i'd be really grateful

I've already tried overriding and disabling the following: border, box-shadow, outline, text-shadow

Code

```
        <li id="id-12">
            <div class="collapsible-header" style="font-size:12px; border-radius: 2px; position: relative !important;">
                <i class="fas fa-horse fa-2x" style="font-size: 40px !important; margin-right: 25px !important; box-shadow: none !important; text-shadow: 0px 0px !important; outline: 0px !important;"></i> 
                <span style="word-break: break-word; box-shadow: none !important; text-shadow: 0px 0px !important; outline: 0px !important;" >X Coin <br> 100</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapsible-body" style="box-shadow: none !important; text-shadow: 0px 0px !important; outline: 0px !important;">
            <div class="row" style="width: 200px; margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; box-shadow: none !important; text-shadow: 0px 0px !important; outline: 0px !important;">
            <div class="input-field col s12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d1cfd9; margin-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding-left: 0px !important;">
              <span style="width: 20px !important; box-shadow: none !important; text-shadow: 0px 0px !important; outline: 0px !important;" class="fas fa-id-card"></span>
              <input value="X (4)" id="tag" type="text" class="validate white-text" disabled style="margin-bottom: 0px !important; padding-bottom: 0px !important; padding-left: 5px !important; border: 0px solid #fff !important; width: 100px !important;">
            </div>       
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
```

Thanks for reading.

Regards.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? What browser/OS/font-awesome version?

Comment: 5.14.0, and here: https://imgur.com/a/rowF3ZW

Comment: Replace <i class="fas fa-horse fa-2x" style="font-size: 40px !important; margin-right: 25px !important; box-shadow: none !important; text-shadow: 0px 0px !important; outline: 0px !important;"></i> with <i class="fa fa-horse fa-2x" ></i>

Comment: Looks like a 2x/1x issue, is this a retina or "standard" monitor?

Comment: @Phix How would the monitor be the problem? It's 144hz monitor

Comment: @Grumpy I tried this, still same result

Comment: Refresh rate != pixel density. If there's not enough/too many pixels that the monitor can render it can cause some rendering artifacts